# Kafka Connect Task Restart `NoSuchMethodError: HttpServletRequest.isAsyncStarted`?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I try to restart a Kafka Connect connector with the following REST command executed via curl:

```
curl -X POST localhost:8083/connectors/my-connector/tasks/0/restart
```

I get HTTP response:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 500 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /connectors/my-connector/tasks/0/restart. Reason:
<pre>    Request failed.</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
</body>
</html>
```

I see Kafka Connect log output. This looks like an internal error in the Kafka Connect REST application.

```
[2017-04-19 17:33:43,783] WARN  (org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler:620)
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "uriTemplate" parameter is null.
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:159)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "uriTemplate" parameter is null.
at org.glassfish.jersey.uri.internal.JerseyUriBuilder.uri(JerseyUriBuilder.java:189)
at org.glassfish.jersey.uri.internal.JerseyUriBuilder.uri(JerseyUriBuilder.java:72)
at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource.completeOrForwardRequest(ConnectorsResource.java:246)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource.completeOrForwardRequest(ConnectorsResource.java:281)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource.restartTask(ConnectorsResource.java:213)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:143)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
... 23 more
[2017-04-19 17:33:43,784] WARN /connectors/my-connector/tasks/0/restart (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel:384)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.isAsyncStarted()Z
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:684)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:159)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-04-19 17:33:43,788] WARN Could not send response error 500: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.isAsyncStarted()Z (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel:4
lines 3767-3832/3832 (END)
```

Comment: We're you able to resolve this?

Comment: Yes, but the issue just seemed to disappear without any classpath changes. I guess that my earlier Connector config was broken? The internal errors are probably still in the REST app but I just managed to avoid them.

Comment: Also, thank you very much for your helpful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced this issue when migrating from CP3.0 to 3.2 version. If you are using CP3.2, "rest-utils" folder was missing from class path. "connect-distributed.sh" was not loading this folder. Please change the sh script to add this folder to class path. This may solve your problem.

Th below folder is missing in classpath:
"confluent-3.2.0\share\java\rest-utils"

Modify the line number 33 in "connect-distributed.sh" as below

```
for library in "confluent-common" "kafka-serde-tools" "rest-utils" "monitoring-interceptors"; do
```